# extract text between single quotes in mult line variable with sed

Tags: bash, variables, sed

I am trying to write a script. I use a remote procedure call with xmlrpc to get a url. I assign the output as a variable all in one command like `url=$(xmlrpc 192.168.1.1 command...)` for example. This is the output of the procedure call when output to a file:

```
Result:

String: 'http://example.url'
```

It all shows up on one line with `echo $url`. When I try to extract the URL between the single quotes with `sed s/^.*'\(.*\)'.*$/\1/ $url` I get the following:

```
sed: can't read Result:: no such file or directory
sed: can't read String:: no such file or directory
sed: can't read http://example.url: no such file or directory
```

Maybe the multiple lines is the problem. I get a similar error with `grep -oP "(?<=').*?(?=')" $url` Any ideas? I just want to extract the URL.

Comment: Why "with sed"?  If this is in bash, for instance, is there a reason you aren't using the shell's native regex support?

Comment: Thats because both sed and grep take a file as an argument, not a string.

Comment: No particular reason I'm using sed. I also tried awk and grep. Didn't think to try the native shell. Whatever works. Good to know, it doesn't take a string as an argument. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -n "s/^.*'\(.*\)'.*$/\1/ p" <<< ${url}
```

Answer (score 2):

With ***bash*** *regular expresssions*:

```
[[ "$url" =~ \'(http:[^\']*)\' ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
http://example.url
```

Comment: This also worked but I had to remove the `http:` part for it to work. Probably because the URL doesn't always start with it. My question was originally about sed so I'll leave the other response as the answer (for posterity) but will use this one for what I need as it's a better way to do what I am trying to accomplish than with sed. I just hadn't considered that method. Thanks.

Comment: @user2328273, you can easily adjust the approach to `[[ "$url" =~ \'([^\']*)\' ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should give native bash regex and replacement a try. If you really want to extract the URL from your multiline variable:

```
$ echo "$url"
Results:

String: 'http://example.url'
```

with sed, then you can use something like this:

```
$ url=$(sed -n "s/^.*'\(.*\)'.*$/\1/p" <<< $var)
$ echo "$url"
http://example.url
```